# mvc3 dropdownlist setting the selected value from model

Tags: javascript, select

I am creating a select list in my .aspx page.

```
<label for="AccessType" class="required"><span class="required">*</span><%=Html.Resource("accessType")%>:</label>
                <select id="AccessType" name="AccessType">
                <% foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Security.AccessType)))
                {%> 
                <option value="<%=(int)item%>"><%=item%> </option> 
                <%}%>
                </select><br />
```

Now every time I load the page it is selecting the first value as default, where as I want the value present in model to be the selected.

I am biniding the dropdown to a enum in my code. Security.AccessType is a enum and not a model. so every time the page loads it shows the selected value of the dropdown as first enum

I want the selected item to be say Model.AccessType...

I know its a very basic question but still any help?

Comment: Not clear from the description, What do you mean by "selecting the first value as default  where as I want the value present in model to be the selected". You are binding the model to the drop down so what ever values you have is populated in your drop-down.

Comment: Ok.. sorry for the non-clarity.. I am biniding the dropdown to a enum in my code. Security.AccessType is a enum and not a model. so every time the page loads it shows the selected value of the dropdown as first enum

Comment: okay. So the dropdown is showing the first value as per binding done to it. So if you want the value of model to be shown you have to bind the model rather than the enum.

Comment: any other way where I can explecitily set the selected value for dropdown

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve , If you want to just set a particular value to be selected item. It can be easily achieved by 'Document.ready' function of Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the followig and got the result..

$('#ddlAccessType').val($("#ddlAccessType option:contains('" + $('#AccessTypeValue').val() + "')").val());

This is first getting the AccessType value then checking for its index in the dropdown list and then setting the selected index to the index found out.

A bit bizzare, but worked fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can give the option which you want to be default a "selected" attribute, like:

```
<option value="apple" selected="selected">apple</option>
```

If you want to select an option dynamically, you can do it by javascript. Eg:

```
var el = document.getElementById("AccessType");
el.selectedIndex = yourIndex; //index of the option you want to select
//or
el.value = "yourValue"; //value of the option you want to select
```

Comment: You mean you need select a option after the list is generated? If this is your condition, you can select an option by javascript. Eg:  var el = document.getElementById("AccessType");el.selectedIndex = yourIndex; or el.value = "yourValue";